# Can arrays be indexed at compile time?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, constexpr, constant-expression

In [this comment to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576363/check-whether-equal-string-literals-are-stored-at-the-same-address#comment39958822_25577498), the user hvd stated the following:

> ... although string literals can be passed to `constexpr` functions,
>   and array indexing is allowed on string literals in constant
>   expressions, an indexing operation on a `constexpr` function parameter
>   doesn't qualify as a constant expression.

I didn't fully understand what was meant. Does it mean that the `hash_value` variable in the following code

```
#include <cstddef>

// Compute the hash of a string literal adding the values of its characters
template<std::size_t N> constexpr std::size_t
hash_string
    ( const char (& s)[N] )
noexcept
{
    std::size_t h = 0;

    // Array indexing happening under the hood
    for ( const auto c : s )
        h += c;

    return h;
}

constexpr auto hash_value = hash_string("Hello, world!");
```

cannot be evaluated at compile time? Could you elaborate on the quoted comment and tell if I am right?

Comment: I don't see anything in C++14 standard that bans this. Your code compiles just fine in clang.

Comment: Do many compilers make this kind of optimization? That seems very aggressive.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, it compiles and works fine for me too on Clang. However, and especially since I don't know assembly, I want to ensure that it is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @Kalrish If you write `constexpr auto foo = ...;`, it must be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Some what related question from yesterday [Computing length of a C string at compile time. Is this really a constexpr?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25890784/1708801) ... assigning to a `constexp` variable means is will be evaluated at compile time and I don't see any issues with your code either.

Comment: @T.C. I thought a `constexpr` declared variable could still exist at run time, at the discretion of the implementation. I will have to revise my `constexpr` knowledge. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Kalrish well Bjarne and Herb both say it should be done at compile time but I can not find the text in the draft standard that requires it and Steve Jessop argues it is a quality of implementation issue and believes they really mean any "self-respecting compilers" should do this.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Well, it must at least qualify for compile-time evaluation as a constant expression.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Well, [your answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25891133/2207421) states it very clear. Taking one of your quotes from Bjarne Stroustrup: "In addition to be able to evaluate expressions at compile time, we want to be able to require expressions to be evaluated at compile time; constexpr in front of a variable definition does that (and implies const)".

Comment: Looking at the assembly output, clang does evaluate this at compile-time. When you turn on optimizations it will evaluate at compile-time even without `constexpr`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour A nonlocal variable initialized with a constant expression qualifies for *constant initialization*, which, as a type of *static initialization*, must be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place. So I suppose compilers could hypothetically defer evaluation until runtime, but they are rather constrained in what they can do even if they defer it.

Comment: @hvd: Can you clarify your comment for OP.

Comment: @T.C. I agree in that case the compiler has more limited options, I was referring to the more general case. When I originally read the code since there was no `main` it was unclear if I should assume `hash_value` was global or it could be either.

Comment: It is at least `as-if` it was evaluated at compile time, with the note that the compiler is free to pause nearly forever at program startup to write sonnets using the infinite monkey technique: few self respecting compilers will do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I was saying in that comment was that you cannot have something like

```
template <int N>
int f();

constexpr int g(int i) {
  return f<i>(); // invalid
}
```

because although the result of a `constexpr` function can be a constant expression, inside the body, its parameters aren't. A `constexpr` function may be called with constant or with non-constant arguments, the caller gets to decide, and C++ doesn't have any sort of function that can *only* be called with constant arguments.

It mattered in the answer you were reading because it would have been useful to have a `const char (&str)[N]` function argument, and treat `str[i]` as a constant expression inside the function body.

This doesn't matter for the code you've got. That code is fine.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it: a `constexpr` function is _enabled_ to be evaluated at compile time, but not _required_. Thus, it may be used in a context in which constant expressions are required, but it cannot be assumed that it will always run at compile time. That's why `constexpr` function arguments cannot be evaluated in a `static_assert`.

Comment: +1 (from yesterday) thank you for following up and clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the relevant sections of both N3337 and N3936, and nothing in either version of the standard prohibits a `constexpr` function of the sort

```
template<std::size_t N> constexpr std::size_t
hash_string
    ( const char (& s)[N] )
noexcept
{
    return s[0];
}
```

And in fact this compiles in both g++ and clang in C++11 mode. I have absolutely no idea where the claim that "an indexing operation on a `constexpr` function parameter doesn't qualify as a constant expression" came from. I can find nothing in §5.19 [expr.const] that prohibits this.

Comment: Can the problem be from use of the `for` loop?

Comment: @RSahu That's a C++14 vs. C++11 issue. The loop isn't allowed in C++11 `constexpr`, but the indexing claim is unrelated to that.

Comment: @hvd I would still like to know the reasons for the quoted statement, even after your standard-based explanation. It intrigues me :).