# C++: Two separate `make_shared` calls to same object will create two separate and independent shared_ptr and its control block?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

1. In the code below, my understanding is a and b are not sharing the ownership. Instead, they are two separate smart pointer, each of them has individual control block with ref_count = 1.
   Is my understanding correct?

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> a = make_shared<Foo>();
std::shared_ptr<Foo> b = make_shared<Foo>();
```

2. the correct way to use shared_ptr which share the ownership and increase ref_cnt is call make_shared once to initialize the memory and use copy/assign to increase the ref_cnt and share owernship. For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> a = make_shared<Foo>();
auto b = a;
auto b(a);
```

Are the two points I mentioned above correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on all counts. Having the same object owned by more than one chain of `shared_ptr` objects is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for answering the questions and confirmation!

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_shared<Foo>` will new up `Foo` object and return you a shared ptr to that object. If you call `std::make_shared`, same thing happens again, you will have new'ed another (independent) `Foo` object.

---

Interesting aside: One instance where you can get (unexpected) sharing for uniquely defined objects are for [string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423837/is-storage-for-the-same-content-string-literals-guaranteed-to-be-the-same).

Comment: Thank you for answering the questions and confirmation!
Indeed interesting side note about string literals !