# Why does "==" return true for character pointers?

Tags: c, string

When we compare strings in C, we are careful to use `strcmp` (or its other variants) to do equality checks. For example, if one string is `char hello1[7] = "hello!"` and another string is `char hello2[7] = "hello!"`, we can check if their contents are equal using `strcmp`. However, we cannot use `==` since `==` will compare the address of the first element of each array (due to array decay), and that is always false.

So why is it that when I try to compare two `char *` with `==`, the result is true? For example:

```
int main() {
  char *str1 = "Hello";
  char *str2 = "Hello";

  if (str1 == str2) {
    printf("equal\n");
  } else {
    printf("not equal\n");
  }
}
```

This will print `equal`. Based on my understanding, a pointer is essentially an address, so a `char *` is an address of a location containing a character. So how can two addresses be the same here?

Comment: see [String Literal address across translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26279717/1708801)

Comment: String literals are often "merged" so that there's only one copy of any given string. Check the pointer values.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid responses! Somehow when I searched I could not find these posts, but they are very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the two addresses *are* the same. Your compiler included one copy of the string "Hello" in your program and made `str1` and `str2` both point to it.

The C standard specifies that [string literals might or might not be distinct arrays in memory, and that undefined things might happen if you modify them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/152948) in order to allow the compiler to do exactly this.