# -O2 and -fPIC option in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-flags

For performance optimization, I would like to make use of the reference of a string rather than its value. Depending on the compilation options, I obtain different results. The behavior is a bit unclear to me, and I do not know the actual `gcc` flag that causes that difference.

My code is

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::string* test2(const std::string& in) {
   // Here I want to make use of the pointer &in
   // ...
   // it's returned only for demonstration purposes...
   return &in;
}

int main() {
   const std::string* t1 = test2("text");
   const std::string* t2 = test2("text");
   // only for demonstration, the cout is printed....
   std::cout<<"References are: "<<(t1==t2?"equivalent. ":"different. ")<<t1<<"\t"<<t2<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

There are three compilation options:

```
gcc main.cc -o main -lstdc++ -O0 -fPIC && ./main
```

```
gcc main.cc -o main -lstdc++ -O2 -fno-PIC && ./main
```

```
gcc main.cc -o main -lstdc++ -O2 -fPIC && ./main
```

The first two yield equivalent results (`References are: different.`), so the pointers are different, but the third one results in equivalent pointers (`References are: equivalent.`).
Why does this happen, and which option do I have to add to the options `-O2 -fPIC` such that the pointers become again different?
Since this code is embedded into a larger framework, I cannot drop the options `-O2` or `-fPIC`.

Since I get the desired result with the option `-O2` and also with `-fPIC`, but a different behavior if both flags are used together, the exact behavior of these flags is unclear to me.

I tried with gcc4.8 and gcc8.3.

Answer (score 3):

Both `t1` and `t2` are dangling pointers, they point to a temporary `std::string` which is already destroyed. The temporary `std::string` is constructed from the string literal during each call to `test2("text")` and lives until the end of the full-expression (the `;`).

Their exact values depend on how the compiler (re-)uses stack space at a particular optimization level.

> which option do I have to add to the options `-O2 -fPIC` such that the pointers become again different?

The code exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because it's [illegal to compare invalid pointer values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694069/is-it-legal-to-compare-dangling-pointers). Simply don't do this.

If we ignore the comparing part, then we end up with this version:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void test2(const std::string& in) {
   std::cout << "Address of in: " << (void*)&in << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   test2("text");
   test2("text");
}
```

Now this code is free from UB, and it will print either the same address or different addresses, depending on how the compiler re-uses stack space between function calls. There is no way to control this, but it's no problem because keeping track of addresses of temporaries is a bad idea to begin with.

You can try using `const char*` as the input argument instead, then no temporary will be created in a call `test2("text")`. But here again, whether or not two instances of `"text"` point to the same location is [implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515903/485343). Though GCC does coalesce identical string literals, so at least in GCC you should observe the behavior you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Of course, one should not make use of these pointers in main (the `cout` is only for demonstration). The purpose is exclusively to make use of the pointers within `test2`, and I would had expected, that the pointers are always different. 
Naively, I expect that otherwise the compiler copies the "text" to a static address, which would be very inefficient.

Comment: @Daniel The compiler can reuse the space for the temporary `std::string` (initialised from `"text"`) it has to create in each expression.  The compiler knows that the temporary (`std::string`) is deleted at the end of each full expression, so it doesn't need to reserve more stack space.

Comment: We could also avoid the invalid pointer issues by doing `reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&in)`. But again, I would not make any assumptions about whether these addresses of temporary objects are the same or different, even staying with a specific compiler like gcc.

Comment: @rustyx. Your reference to standard (C++11 §2.14.5 String Literals) exactly answered my question. Thanks!
Even when using `const char*` there is no guarantee that two calls pass two different pointers to that function, since gcc coalesces identical string values.

Still, it would be nice to have an opportunity in C++ to get a unique pointer for each function call.